# how many inner exception may exists in a single exception handling in C#?

Tags: inner-exception

how many inner exceptions may exist in a single exception handling in C#?

how many levels of Inner exception may have in the exception handling in c#.

Comment: are you speaking about nested exceptions ? Could you give a little definition of innner exceptions or a link to a little explanation or definition ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no hard-coded limit. The only possible limit would be the size of your RAM memory (plus paging/swap size).